# How to convert BigDecimal to BigInt in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using a formula for calculation, and the code looks like the following:

```
import { BigInt, BigDecimal } from '@graphprotocol/graph-ts'

const amount = BigDecimal.fromString('150').times(BigDecimal.fromString('0.999216459'))
```

The `amount` is a `BigDecimal` value. How I can convert `BigDecimal` to `BigInt` like the following:

```
149.51 => 150
149.49 => 149
```

Comment: Do you mean how to round a number in javascript? Or are you talking about a specific library? You need to clarify the question, we can't guess as to the code you are looking at.

Comment: Yes, round + change the type from BigDecimal to BigInt

Comment: What is BigDecimal, what is BigInt? Are these public libraries? If so include links to them and also include a working example of what it is you are talking about.

Comment: Sure, updated the question

Comment: @Igor BigInt is a javascript built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string representation, you can use the BigInt function:

```
const str = '123.123';
const bi = BigInt(str.split('.')[0]);
```

This will strip the decimals, but not round. If you want rounding just use BigDecimals rounding feature before you generate the string. It looks like it does support this.

Note that the last BigDecimal release appears to be 10 years ago, so perhaps it might be better to go with a more modern library. You might like [mine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-money) if you're doing financial calculations.